# Remote connect to SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: php, sql-server

This question might fit better on Serverfault, but I'm not sure where the actual problems are so I'll start asking here.

I've just installed a Windows Server 2012 with SQL server 2008 R2 SP1. We usually monitor our SQL Servers from a php script testing connections and such, but I cannot connect to this specific server. The errorlog says "Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided" but when copy/pasting the exact same username/password into Management Studio on the local server or a remote server everything works. I think it is because the 2012 OS, but not entirely sure and hope that anyone can give me some pointers.

There are no firewalls between the Server running the SQL and the server doing the monitoring and remote connections are allowed. The tested users all have permission to connect to the database engine, login enabled and any password policies disabled.

The PHP version is 5.3.3, I'm using freeTDS and protocolversion 8.0. Lastly this is all configuration options relating to mssql in php.ini

```
mssql mssql.allow_persistent => On 
mssql.batchsize => 0 
mssql.charset => no value 
mssql.compatability_mode => Off 
mssql.connect_timeout => 5 
mssql.datetimeconvert => On  
mssql.max_links => Unlimited  
mssql.max_persistent => Unlimited 
mssql.max_procs => Unlimited 
mssql.min_error_severity => 10 
mssql.min_message_severity
mssql.secure_connection => Off 
mssql.textlimit => Server default 
mssql.textsize => Server default
mssql.timeout => 60
```

Comment: is the server set to allow mixed-mode authentication? php may be trying to use sql server credentials, while the server's expecting  only domain logins.

Comment: Yes, mixed-mode is on and the login in question is a SQL Server login NOT a domain login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was wrong about the TCP connection rights, and this was not a programming/php specific error. The following blog post describes the problem if anyone in the future stumbles on this question with the same error.

http://dbccpage.wordpress.com/2011/11/19/how-to-solve-error-18456-severity-14-state-12-login-based-server-access-validation-failed-with-an-infrastructure-error-check-for-previous-errors/

I have no idea why this problem only emerges on our Windows Server 2012 machines, but that seems to be the case for us.